# How to trigger email on submitting salesforce form?

Tags: php, salesforce

I have a form which submits the information to the Salesforce.I want to trigger an email with the information filled in the form as I click on the submit button.

How to do this that form is also submitted and email is also triggered.

Following is the form code.

```
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<input type=hidden name="oid" value="somevalue">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://example.com">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="developer@domain.com">    -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your best bet may be to create a handler page that serves the function of sending your form information to the SalesForce page as well as sending an email, rather than just sending your information directly to SalesForce.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, POST data is available through the [`$_POST` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).
The content of your `first_name` input will be found in `$_POST['first_name']`.

Now to send a mail in PHP all you need if your server is properly configured is the `mail()` function.

Comment: @Sebastian I am not posting the data to the same page as action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>

Comment: The POST data will be available to the page where you post the form, which is defined in the action attribute (in your example: `https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead`)

Comment: @Sebastian I do not have access to https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead

Comment: Then I do not understand your question.